# Build failling while trying to build object file in separate directory using makefile in a c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I am trying to build the objects and .exe file into a separate directory name App using Makefile, but the build fails. Objects files did not copy into the App directory.

```
CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++20 -pedantic -ggdb
EXECUTABLE_NAME = akash
MEMORY_SAFE_FLAGS= -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
BUILD_DIR = App

CXX_SOURCES = $(wildcard  src/*.cpp src/**/*.cpp)  
CXX_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(CXX_SOURCES)) 

all: build execute 

build: $(CXX_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXX_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

execute:
    ./$(BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

**Error:**

```bash
make: *** No rule to make the target 'App/src/Player/Player.o, needed by 'build'. stop.
```

```
drwxrwxr-x    - akashdiphazra  3 Jul 23:17 ├──  App (Dir of object and exe files)
.rwxrwxr-x  35k akashdiphazra  3 Jul 23:17 │  
.rwxrwxr-x  619 akashdiphazra  3 Jul 23:17 ├── Makefile
drwxrwxr-x    - akashdiphazra  3 Jul 23:17 └── src (Dir)
.rwxrwxr-x  205 akashdiphazra  3 Jul 14:29    ├── main.cpp
                                              |
drwxrwxr-x    - akashdiphazra  3 Jul 23:17    └── Player (Dir)
.rwxrwxr-x  135 akashdiphazra  3 Jul 14:24       ├── Player.cpp
.rwxrwxr-x  284 akashdiphazra  3 Jul 14:24       ├── Player.h
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output from when running `make`. There's no way for us to guess what error you get.

Comment: It seems your way of creating the list of object files for `make` will need a copy of the source file directory hierarchy. So your rules expects the source file `src/Player/Player.cpp` is built into the object file `App/src/Player/Player.o`. Either you need to make sure there's a matching directory hierarchy for the object files, and that you have rules to match the proper object files with their corresponding source file. Or you need to flatten the directory hierarchy so `make` want to use `App/Player.o`.

Comment: Is there is any way to copy the all object file into App directory and build from there, that's what i am trying to achieve.